# Optimise SQL query with Case and operations in the select statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is there a way to optimise the query below.

It currently takes around 2 minutes to run

I'm using MS SQL. The Records_Table has nearly 9 million records. Date field is stored in 30 minute intervals and there are 60 different types of groups

```
declare @date datetime
set @date = convert(datetime,'16/sep/2013',104)

SELECT 
[Group],
CASE WHEN (SUM(A) + SUM(B)) = 0 THEN 0 ELSE 
CAST(SUM(C) AS decimal(18, 2)) / (SUM(A) + SUM(B)) * 100 END AS Calculation 
FROM   Records_Table
WHERE date BETWEEN @Date AND @Date + 6
GROUP BY [Group]
```

Note that I need a full week of data, so I've set the condition as date BETWEEN @Date AND @Date + 6

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What indexes do you have on your table?

Comment: I ran the following query and I don'g get any result (therefore, none): select * from sys.indexes where object_id = (select object_id from sys.objects where name = 'Records_Table')

Comment: I'd suggest an index on Date then, and include the columns you need as non key columns. e.g. `CREATE INDEX IX_RecordsTable_Date ON Records_Table (Date) INCLUDE ([Group], A, B, C)`

Comment: You won't get a full week of data. Use `WHERE date >= @date AND date < @date + 7` or even better `WHERE date >= @date AND date < DATEADD(day, 7, @date)`

Comment: A must read: **[What do BETWEEN and the devil have in common?](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common)**

Answer (score 0):

Try partitioning your table based on Date, because as I understand your conditions mostly based on Date, and you can simply create index on Date, but because of 9 million row you have i prefer partitioning.

Comment: Will I need administator access to create partitioning? Any way around that?

Comment: You must have the ALTER OBJECT privilege on that table

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest an index on (Date,Group) so the date is optimized for the date range in question, and the Group for the group by qualifier for aggregates.